# Adding NA's where data is missing

Tags: r

I have a dataset that look like the following

```
id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
cycle = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,2)
value = 1:9

data.frame(id,cycle,value)

> data.frame(id,cycle,value)
  id cycle value
1  1     1     1
2  1     2     2
3  1     3     3
4  2     1     4
5  2     2     5
6  2     3     6
7  3     1     7
8  3     3     8
9  4     2     9
```

so basically there is a variable called `id` that identifies the sample, a variable called `cycle` which identifies the timepoint, and a variable called `value` that identifies the value at that timepoint.

As you see, sample 3 does not have cycle 2 data and sample 4 is missing cycle 1 and 3 data. What I want to know is there a way to run a command outside of a loop to get the data to place `NA`'s where there is no data. So I would like for my dataset to look like the following:

```
> data.frame(id,cycle,value)
   id cycle value
1   1     1     1
2   1     2     2
3   1     3     3
4   2     1     4
5   2     2     5
6   2     3     6
7   3     1     7
8   3     2    NA
9   3     3     8
10  4     1    NA
11  4     2     9
12  4     3    NA
```

I am able to solve this problem with a lot of loops and if statements but the code is extremely long and cumbersome (I have many more columns in my real dataset).

Also, the number of samples I have is very large so I need something that is generalizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `merge` and `expand.grid`, we can come up with a solution. `expand.grid` creates a `data.frame` with all combinations of the supplied vectors (so you'd supply it with the `id` and `cycle` variables). By merging to your original data (and using `all.x = T`, which is like a `left join` in SQL), we can fill in those rows with missing data in `dat` with `NA`.

```
id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
cycle = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,2)
value = 1:9

dat <- data.frame(id,cycle,value)

grid_dat <- expand.grid(id = 1:4,
                        cycle = 1:3)

# or you could do (HT @jogo):
# grid_dat <- expand.grid(id = unique(dat$id), 
#                         cycle = unique(dat$cycle))

merge(x = grid_dat, y = dat, by = c('id','cycle'), all.x = T)

   id cycle value
1   1     1     1
2   1     2     2
3   1     3     3
4   2     1     4
5   2     2     5
6   2     3     6
7   3     1     7
8   3     2    NA
9   3     3     8
10  4     1    NA
11  4     2     9
12  4     3    NA
```

Comment: or `grid_dat <- expand.grid(id = unique(dat$id), cycle = unique(dat$cycle))`

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on the package `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data frame
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
cycle <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2)
value <- 1:9

dt <- data.frame(id, cycle, value)

# Complete the combination between id and cycle
dt2 <- dt %>% complete(id, cycle)
```

Comment: my word, @hadley has thought of everything

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `data.table` doing a *cross join*:

```
library("data.table")
d <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4), cycle = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,2), value = 1:9)
d[CJ(id=id, cycle=cycle, unique=TRUE), on=.(id,cycle)]
```